# Detect SSL/TLS Client Authentication with Python?

Tags: python, ssl

I have multiple Web Servers (mostly IIS & Apache).

Some of them are configured to allow only clients with a specific certificate. Moreover, we have users that have multiple certificates for the same web server which allows different actions to be made.

**Ex** : Certificates that are used only for highly privileged actions and some for everyday use.

We do not use the operating system certificate store for compliance issues.

I have made the following python code which works by specifying the wanted certificate :

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://myserver-dns-name.com", cert="./ClientCert.Key")
```

I tried fetching the server certificate and look for the following enhanced key usage oid *1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1* (TLS Server Auth) but not all servers have it specified.

I tried using the Python ssl library and handle the handshake but the library doesn't seems to allow it. What I wanted is have a callback when the server sends a certificate request to the client.

What I want to know is if its possible to detect from the client that the server have client authentication enforced in Python or any other languages?

I want to implement the same behavior as chromium in Python (Showing a certificate selection dialog as seen here [ssl_client_auth_handler.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/55f44515cd0b9e7739b434d1c62f4b7e321cd530/content/browser/ssl/ssl_client_auth_handler.cc))

Comment: If the server wants a client certificate it requests it with a specific TLS frame of "CertificateRequest".  You won't see it with high level API such as requests. If you want to see it you need to go below and handle the TLS handshake yourself. But the fact that the server sends it to you does not prove it would sent it to any client. The server can be configured to ask certificates only based on some external criterias like the source IP address or the content of the ClientHello for extreme cases.